# Showing existence of a solution to a quadratic system of equations implies existence of a solution to another

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms, nonlinear-system, quadratic-programming, nonlinear-analysis

Given a system of quadratic equations:

$$\forall i\>\>\>x^{\dagger}M_ix = y_i$$

I want to show that if there exists a solution $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$, there must also exist  a solution $\hat{x}$ such that:

$$\forall i\>\>\>\hat{x}^{\dagger}M_i\hat{x} = -y_i$$

Or in other words the system of quadratic equations:

$$\forall i\>\>\>x^{\dagger}(-M_i)x = y_i$$

Under what conditions does this hold? By definition, $M_i$ can't be definite; otherwise, the quadratic forms will always be either positive or negative. Are there any other conditions that are needed to make this true?

In my case, $M_i$ is defined as:

$$M_1 =\begin{bmatrix} 0 & ... & 0 &0 &1 \\
0 & ... & 0 &0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 \\
. & . & . & .& .\\
0 & 0 &... &0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$M_2 =\begin{bmatrix} 0 & ... &0 & 1 &0 \\
0 & ... &0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0\\
. & . & . & .& .\\
0 & 0 &... &0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$M_3 =\begin{bmatrix} 0 &... & 1 & 0 &0 \\
0 & ... &0& 1 & 0   \\ 
0 & ... &0& 0 & 1\\
. & . & . & .& .\\
0 & 0 &... & 0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
All the way to $M_{n-1}$:
$$M_{n-1}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1& 0&...  & 0 &0 \\
0 &0&1 &0&... &0   \\ 
0 &0&0 &1&... &0   \\ 
. & . & . & .& .& .\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0&1\\
0 & 0 &... & 0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

So $M_i$ are matrices with diagonals of 1s moving from top right corner down as $i$ goes to $n-1$

Comment: Wouldn't $\hat{x} := x \sqrt{-1}$ be a solution to the second equation?

Comment: @SamForster No because then you would get $\hat{x}^{\dagger}M_i\hat{x} = (i)(-i)x^{\dagger}M_ix = x^{\dagger}M_ix = y_i$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It's a part of some research I'm doing and I've been able to reduce my problem to the above.  If the above is true, then it would prove for all polynomials $P$ there exists a polynomial $Q$ such that $\vert\vert P\vert\vert^2 + \vert\vert Q\vert\vert^2 = k$ on the unit circle for some constant $k$, this would then prove some powerful results about an algorithm I've come up with.

Comment: @Dani007 Please include such information in the question itself.

Comment: @Dani007 Sorry of course, it's been a long day. Are you assuming that the $M_i$ matrices have complex entries, or real entries?

Comment: @SamForster Real entries. I edited the question to reflect the $M_i$ I'm interested in.